# Unity3d - UnityWebRequest to run php code

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have a php file which will increase a counter in a database. I want it so that I can increase the counter from inside the C# script in Unity3d. Is there a way of updating the database by calling the php script from C#?

I've checked the Unity documentation for UnityWebRequest and nothing is to do with simply 'opening' a url (without opening in the browser) or updating a database. I tried using UnityWebRequest and also the now obselete WWW but haven't got either of them to work.

I can't actually upload any code at the moment because the server I'm using is down, but I'll do it as soon as it's back online. (This isn't the reason nothing seems to be working.)

Comment: There's [an example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) that shows how to `GET` an URL. Instead of `"https://www.example.com"` you should use something like `"http://localhost/nameOfYourScript.php"

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple web request to your get page in php.

you can also build your url with parameters if you need aditional functionality

```
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        //http://localhost:3000/ if you are executing on same machine
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("www.yoursite.com/increaseCounter"))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
               //check errors
            }
            else
            {
               //all ok
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your php file working correctly? if yes then you will probably need to create a form and add counter to that form as an argument, then create a post request inside the unity3d script and call it with UnityWebRequest.

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("counter", 1);
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("URL to your PHP file", form);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError){
   Debug.Log("Form Upload Failed");
}
else{
   Debug.Log("Form Upload Complete");
}
```

Hope that helps